# Как в Scilab 5.5.2 сгладить график?

Tags: scilab

Как в Scilab 5.5.2 сгладить график например вот такой

```
x=[1 9 15 23 30 35];
y=[4 66 19 43 24 33];
plot(x,y);
```

Comment: А как конкретно нужно сгладить? Интерполяция (гладкий график проходит через все точки) или регрессия под конкретную гладкую функцию (параболу, экспоненту итд)?

Comment: Первый вариант "Интерполяция (гладкий график проходит через все точки)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Scilab есть подходящая функция [interp1](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/ru_RU/interp1.html), аналогичная [функции matlab](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
x=[1 9 15 23 30 35];
y=[4 66 19 43 24 33];
xp=linspace(0,35,100);
[yp]=interp1(x, y, xp, 'spline');
```